# Filtering a list of knockout.js components

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to find the most "knockout" way of doing this.

I've got a list of files that are fetched via a GET request and are stuffed into an array in my template's view model. I iterate through those in the template and create a `<partial-li-file>` for each item.

I'm trying to filter the files from a searchbox. I was able to do this in a previous iteration where `PartialLiFile` objects were held in the array but now it's just a list of Objects.

I don't see where or how I can access the `PartialLiFile` objects to filter them.

Is it even possible to do this like I've got it implemented here?

#### Template

```
<ul data-bind="foreach:files">
    <partial-li-file params="{fil:$data}" data-bind="visible:!filtered()"></partial-li-file>
</ul>
```

#### Main ViewModel

```
self.search = ko.observable();

self.search.subscribe(function(text) {
    // TODO: Need to filter the files here
});

// Fetch the file data
self.files = ko.observableArray();
$.getJSON("get/files/", function(data) {
    data.map(function(fil) {
        self.files.push(fil);
    });
});
```

#### Partial ViewModel

```
function PartialLiFile(params) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(params.fil, {}, self);

    // TODO: need to set this to true if the name matches the search string
    self.filtered = ko.observable(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error I've figured out the answer. I added the parent's search observable, `$parent.search`, to the list of parameters passed into the component and subscribed to it int he partial's view model. I didn't realize that it was possible to share an observable in this way.

#### Template

```
<ul data-bind="foreach:files">
    <partial-li-file params="{fil:$data,search:$parent.search}" data-bind="visible:!filtered()"></partial-li-file>
</ul>
```

#### Partial ViewModel

```
function PartialLiFile(params) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(params.fil, {}, self);

    self.search = params.search;

    self.search.subscribe(function(search) {
        self.filtered(self.name().search(new RegExp(search, "i")) == -1);
    });

    self.filtered = ko.observable(false);
}
```